# NullPointerException while reading a column from the row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

The following Scala (Spark 1.6) code for reading a value from a Row fails with a `NullPointerException` when the value is null.

```
val test = row.getAs[Int]("ColumnName").toString
```

while this works fine

```
val test1 = row.getAs[Int]("ColumnName") // returns 0 for null
val test2 = test1.toString // converts to String fine
```

What is causing `NullPointerException` and what is the recommended way to handle such cases?

PS: getting row from DataFrame as follows:

```
val myRDD = myDF.repartition(partitions)
  .mapPartitions{ rows => 
    rows.flatMap{ row =>
      functionWithRows(row) //has above logic to read null column which fails
    }
  }
```

`functionWithRows` has then above mentioned `NullPointerException`.

MyDF schema:

```
root
 |-- LDID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- KTAG: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ColumnName: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the entire stacktrace? I can't seem to reproduce the issue with the recent version of Spark 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: I have abstracted out my production code. Using spark 1.6.1 it gives NullPointerException for the line:
val test = row.getAs[Int]("ColumnName").toString

Comment: @JacekLaskowski This does throw NPE `spark.sql(" select 1 as col union all select null as col").map(_.getAs[Int]("col").toString ).collect`. Removing `toString` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAs` is defined as:

```
def getAs[T](i: Int): T = get(i).asInstanceOf[T]
```

and when we do toString we call `Object.toString` which doesn't depend on the type, so `asInstanceOf[T]` get dropped by the compiler, i.e.

```
row.getAs[Int](0).toString -> row.get(0).toString
```

we can confirm that by writing a simple scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object Test {
  val row = Row(null)
  row.getAs[Int](0).toString
}
```

and then compiling it:

```
$ scalac -classpath $SPARK_HOME/jars/'*' -print test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  object Test extends Object {
    private[this] val row: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def row(): org.apache.spark.sql.Row = Test.this.row;
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      Test.this.row = org.apache.spark.sql.Row.apply(scala.this.Predef.genericWrapArray(Array[Object]{null}));
      Test.this.row().getAs(0).toString();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

So the proper way would be:

```
String.valueOf(row.getAs[Int](0))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid null values, it is a better practice is to use `isNullAt` before checking, as the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getAs(java.lang.String)) suggests:

> **getAs**
>
> `<T> T getAs(int i)`
>
> Returns the value at position `i`. For primitive types if value is null it 
>   returns 'zero value' specific for primitive ie. `0` for `Int` - use `isNullAt` to ensure that value is not null

I agree the behaviour is confusing, though.